# Using indents and line breaks together

Tags: novel, formatting

I am sorry if has been asked before. I was wondering if that both Indent and Line Break in the same text are allowed (I've seen it used in some old texts and I am wondering if it still an acceptable format to use). An example of this:

```
   There was a boy who loved potatoes and farmed them all day and ate them and
fried them everyday.
   'I simply love my potatoes', he always said to his father.

   One day he lost all his potatoes because...
```

If not, what do you think is the better way to connect different things or times (Like between day and night after a sleep) in story. Just an indent or reconstruct into into two different chapters?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Azeez.  Glad you found us.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].

Comment: You're welcome to edit your post however you wish, it is yours after all.  But I promise you, "everday" is not a word.  It really is "everyday."

Comment: And re-welcome, now as Darkmaster Z.

Answer (score 2):

Line breaks are used in addition to indents in many novels. They indicate a substantial time gap or a complete change of subject or setting. They are a bit like a chapter break.

Usually, text after a line break is not indented.